# Creating multiple objects from a single source file using cmake

Tags: cmake

Using `cmake`, is there a way to generate n-unique object files from a single source file?

I saw [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55724483) for `autotool` (of which I know how to do) but nothing for `cmake` ... yet.

```
#  Make three unique object files 
#  from a single source file

set_source_files_properties(source.c
    TARGET source_1
    OBJECT_OUTPUT source_1.o
    COMPILER_FLAGS -DCODE_LOGIC1
)
set_source_files_properties(source.c
    TARGET source_2
    OBJECT_OUTPUT source_2.o
    COMPILER_FLAGS -DCODE_LOGIC2
)
set_source_files_properties(source.c
    TARGET source_3
    OBJECT_OUTPUT source_3.o
    COMPILER_FLAGS -DCODE_LOGIC3
)
add_executable(myexec source_1 source_2 source_3)
```

The above doesn't work.

Comment: Does something along `add_library(source_${i} source.c) target_compile_definitions(source_${i} -DCODE_LOGIC${i})` work? Then just `add_executable(myexec "")` with `target_link_libraries(myexec source_1 source_2 source_3)`

Comment: @KamilCuk With normal `add_library` you would create  `.so`/`.a` files, but he only wants the object files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`add_library(<name> OBJECT <source>)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#object-libraries). With that in mind, you can do:

```
add_library(source_1 OBJECT source.c)
target_compile_options(source_1 PUBLIC -DLOGIC1)

add_library(source_2 OBJECT source.c)
target_compile_options(source_2 PUBLIC -DLOGIC2)

add_library(source_3 OBJECT source.c)
target_compile_options(source_3 PUBLIC -DLOGIC3)

add_executable(myexec $<TARGET_OBJECTS:source_1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:source_2> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:source_3>)
```

Comment: This introduces a concept of CMake's OBJECT that is so poorly documented, especially when in contrast with 'TARGET'; two different beasts.